# What to combine this into single line

Tags: php

I have no idea why this does not work well.

What wrong with this?

```
define('banana', TRUE);
define('papaya', TRUE);
define('salmon', TRUE);
define('roster', TRUE);
```

I turn it into single line but nothing?

```
define('banana', 'papaya', 'salmon', 'roster', TRUE);
```

Comment: It only takes 1 value. http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php

Comment: @pradeep PHP 7 can define multiple constants in a single `define` call?

Comment: @pradeep the OP does not want to define a constant whose variable is an array. They want to define multiple constants using a single call to [`define()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php). This is not possible, even on PHP 7.

Answer (score 0):

As [chris85](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4333555/chris85) has said, you can only specify one name of a constant. As per the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php):

> (PHP 4, PHP 5, PHP 7)
>
> define — Defines a named constant
>
> bool define ( string $name , mixed $value [, bool $case_insensitive = FALSE ] )

You need to concatenate (*using a period*; `.`) them to show them on a single line, although as you're defining them as having a boolean value of true, it won't say much.

You could do:

```php
define('banana', 'yellow');
define('papaya', 'yellowy orange');
define('salmon', 'red');
define('roster', 'yummy');

echo banana . ', ' . papaya . ', ' . salmon . ', ' . roster;
```

Which would give you:

```
yellow, yellowy orange, red, yummy
```